# Sort posts alphabetically on a specific page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, posts

**EDIT:** Found my old code, that worked, and got it fixed that way. Also gonna use a plugin to add custom functions, to avoid it dissaperaing again with next theme update (Thanks Heba). And the code:

```
function foo_modify_query_order( $query ) { 
if (get_the_ID()==80) { $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' ); $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' ); } } add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'foo_modify_query_order' );
```

So, it should be a simple task, but I have no idea why it's not working by now. I have tried everything, every Google link is purple, so now I hope someone can tell me what it is, I'm doing wrong.

I should start by mentioning that it's a Divi theme, but I did get it to work a few months ago, but forgot how, and I can't recreate it now.

I'm just trying to sort the main query alphabetically (A-Z), but only on a page called recipes. The site have all the recipes as posts, together with their blog posts, but the blog posts are sorted by date and showed on a separate page, which works fine.

But weird stuff are happening, when I try and alter it. If I use this code, **it actually works**, but the blog page also get sorted alphabetically, which it shouldn't.

```
function foo_modify_query_order( $query ) {
    if (is_archive()) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'foo_modify_query_order' );
```

Which doesn't make sense to me, since it's posts? Out of all the ways I've tried, it only sorts if I use is_archive().

If I try to make it check for a specific page first, like `&& is_page('recipes')` I get an error.

If I just add `if (is_page('recipes')){ echo 'Recipes'; }` it works, but if I try to add the sorting inside, I get nothing.

So partially working, but I can't combine the two. Is it a Divi issue or am I doing it wrong? Hope anyone can help, I've tried so many different things now. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a child theme where you will create a new page template to be used in the 'recipes' page.

First, use [Child Theme Configurator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/) plugin to set a new child theme, don't forget to select Copy Menus, Widgets and other Customizer Settings from the Parent Theme to the Child Theme option to keep your settings:

[image: copy theme settings to child theme]

After that, from files tab in the child theme configurator, copy the page template used for blog (or the page template used in 'recipes' page).

After that, change the file name, and the name written in the top of the page template file after Template Name, to recipes ordered alphabetically or any name you would prefer like next:

```
/*
 * Template Name: recipes ordered alphabetically
 */
```

You can add these args to the query:

$args['orderby'] = 'title';
$args['order'] = 'ASC';

And change 'recipes' page template to the new created one.
For more detailed answer, Please insert the code used in the page template.

Comment: Hello Heba, thanks for the good respone. I could easily see creating a child theme , would fix it pretty fast, like you are saying, but it's not an option atm, I'm afraid. I was just asked to try and quickly fix this "small" problem, I can't persuade them to make it a child theme, it's a pretty big site already.

Comment: I see, in this case, can you please identify the type of 'recipes' page? is it a page that uses blog template, or it is archive page for recipes post type?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the first one. A standard page, where it list all the posts (recipes). The recipes are categorized individually for each type, like, 'Vegetarian', 'Fish', 'Salat', and so on. There's no custom post types. It's just weird how I can get it to echo something, and only on that page I ask it to. And I can get it to sort all posts alphabetically, but when I combine the two, no luck.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, in this case, the blog template page is probably using a custom query. I think we will need to check the query of the blog template page php if it is possible.

Comment: Sorry as well, was a bit busy yesterday. We worked on getting an old build back online on a test server, to see the old code I used to make it work a month ago, as I mentioned. Tried it out, and it actually works again. Now we just need to figure out how to make the code stay, when the theme updates, as he's not using child theme. But thanks a lot for the help so far :)

Comment: Oh btw, here's the code that actually works. Forgot I used "get_the_id" to target the correct page.

```function foo_modify_query_order( $query ) {
    if (get_the_ID()==80) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'foo_modify_query_order' ); ```

Comment: That's great :) Please edit your post to put the correction. Also, you can use Custom Functions plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-custom-functions/ to add functions so that they won't be overwritten by theme updates.

Comment: Oh, never even thought of that. That's a nice solution, actually. Thanks once again Heba. Glad you wanted to give my post some attention. I will edit my post :)